# AlarmReceiver Notification not displaying on API Level 28

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I have two projects exactly the same, one running API 26 target and another API 28. I am trying to use an alarm manager to trigger a notification, this works fine on the API 26 but when I put it into my API 28 project nothing works. I have everything exactly the same so I am failing to understand why this won't appear. Has anyone experienced anything similar? I will attach all the codes below and also my manifest.

After the 10 seconds defined, and 25 seconds I receive the logs as I should I just don't get the notifications. Logs are below:

```
11-08 14:51:50.963 27292-27292/uareloaded.uareloaded
E/NotificationManager: notifyAsUser: tag=null, id=0,
user=UserHandle{0} 11-08 14:51:55.803
27292-27292/uareloaded.uareloaded V/ActivityThread: Handle window
ActivityRecord{d7e10f1 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2edee5a
{uareloaded.sap.uareloaded/uareloaded.uareloaded.MainActivity}}
visibility: false 11-08 14:52:05.957 27292-27292/uareloaded.uareloaded
E/NotificationManager: notifyAsUser: tag=null, id=0,
user=UserHandle{0}
```

**AlarmReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.singhajit.notificationDemo.channelId";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        String passed = intent.getStringExtra("test");
        String passed2 = intent.getStringExtra("test2");
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
String messageBody = "Your event " + passed + " is about to start in 15 minutes, in room "+passed2;
       // PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 999, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        builder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle(builder)
                .bigText(messageBody)
                .setBigContentTitle("UA Reloaded Event Starting")
                .setSummaryText("Tap To View Info"))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) builder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            String description = "UA Reloaded Event";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH; //Important for heads-up notification
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", CHANNEL_ID, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
           // NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addNotification(10,"eventname","roomname");
        addNotification(25,"eventname2","roomname2");
    }
    public void addNotification(int test, String test2, String test3){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("test",test2);
        intent.putExtra("test2",test3);
        final int _id = 50;
        Random random = new Random();
        final int randomInt = random.nextInt();
        System.out.println("random integer:" + randomInt);
        PendingIntent appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, randomInt, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, test);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), appIntent);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uareloaded.uareloaded">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".schedule" />
        <activity android:name=".Twitter" />
        <activity android:name=".Menti" />
        <activity android:name=".ScheduleDetail" />
        <activity android:name=".Info" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Beacons" />
        <activity android:name=".AR" />
        <activity android:name=".Favorites" />
        <activity android:name=".Exhibitors" />
        <activity android:name=".ExhibitorsDetail" />
        <activity android:name=".Badges"/>
        <activity android:name=".NotificationActivity" />

        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

NotificationChannel takes 3 parameters which are

1. String id
2. String name
3. int importance

You are creating notification channel with channel id as "1"

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", CHANNEL_ID, importance);
```

but while setting the channel id, you are setting as
`builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);` where CHANNEL_ID is `private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.singhajit.notificationDemo.channelId";`

Create the notification channel using the same id like this:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channelName", importance);
```

This `channelName` will be displayed as the Notification Category to the users in their App Notifications settings. The `description` will be displayed as the description of the notification category. Hence, choose the `channelName` and `description` appropriately.

For more details you can refer to the developer guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels).